# Let $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ so $\exists A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ that is invertible and that verify $AB$ is an upper triangular matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

*Question:*
True or False. If $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, then $\exists A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ that is invertible such that $AB$ is an upper triangular matrix.

*Answer:*
I think that the answer is true but i don't succeed to prove it for matrices $B$ which are not invertible. In fact i thought of prove it by recursion but it seems to me very heavy. So I would be happy to read other and more simple solutions.

To prove it for invertible matrices you just take $A=B^{-1}$.

Thank for your help

Comment: See [QR factorisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition).

Comment: Thank for your answer, does a prove by induction work here?

Comment: QR factorisation is already a recursive algorithm.

Comment: @X0 Alternatively, using [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) we can produce an invertible matrix $A$ such that $AB$ is in [reduced row-echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) (RREF), and every RREF matrix is also upper-triangular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user1551 said this is true. You can read more about it here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition